# Why do I get this noMethodError error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the error:

```
NoMethodError in VideosController#update

undefined method `each' for #<Topic:0x1032ee330>
```

This is the application trace:

```
app/models/video.rb:19:in `assign_topics'
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:41:in `update'
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:40:in `update'
```

this is my `assign_topics` method:

```
def assign_topics
  if @topic_names
    self.topics = Topic.find_or_create_by_name(@topic_names)
  end
end
```

Note that I'm following this: http://media.railscasts.com/videos/167_more_on_virtual_attributes.mov

Here's the video controller's update method:

```
def update
    @video = current_user.videos.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.update_attributes(params[:video])
        format.html { redirect_to(@video, :notice => 'Video was successfully updated.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that your `assign_topics` method is at fault. `Topic.find_or_create_by_name` will return a single `Topic` instance, then you assign that to `self.topics` and `self.topics` is probably expecting an [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) (or some other [`Enumerble`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html)); then later, the update process will try to loop through `self.topics` using `each` and you get your error.

You mention, in a comment, that you tried something like this:

```
self.topics = @topic_names.each { |n| Topic.find_or_create_by_name(n) }
```

But that won't work because [`each` returns the original array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000231) and so the above is equivalent to this:

```
@topic_names.each { |n| Topic.find_or_create_by_name(n) }
self.topics = @topic_names
```

and all the `Topic` instances that you found/created are simply thrown away.

So, you might have better luck using [`collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000247) like this:

```
def assign_topics
    if @topic_names
        self.topics = @topic_names.collect { |n| Topic.find_or_create_by_name(n) }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NoMethodError Exception` because somewhere in your code you are trying to loop, via `.each()`, on something that is not an array/enumerable.

According to your exception, you are calling `.each()` on a Model Object(Topic), which would make sense to not have the `.each()` method.

Comment: Judging from the name of your variables, `@topic_names` contains an array which you can't pass into `find_or_create_by_*`

Comment: yeah... I tried something like this: self.topics = @topic_names.each do |name|
        Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end

Comment: But that gave me this error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in VideosController#update

Topic(#2173382840) expected, got String(#2148246520)`

Comment: You want to to use `map`/`collect` instead of `each`.